# Getting intersection between two rasters using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, intersection

I'm in a middle of a task where I have to extract the intersection between two rasters.

I need to obtain this overlapping portion of the rasters where they touch themselves.
The result I expect is something like this piece in red.

[image: screenshot]

In other words, it's similar to the Intersection function on QGIS (but this only works with vectors).

Is there something like this for rasters?

Comment: Have a look at Raster calculator: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_analysis.html?highlight=raster%20calculator#id4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [@Babel](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/88814/babel) has suggested, Raster calculator is the best tool.

For your case, there is also a useful (and relatively new) **Raster boolean AND** tool in the Processing Toolbox > Raster analysis group.

This is a small example, *E100N90* is a background SRTM topo (sea level 0 m is set to nodata) and *Rectangle* is a hand-drawn reddish rectangle. You will notice **Raster boolean AND** tool at the right-hand side is highlighted yellow.

[image]

Just run **Raster boolean AND** tool and select these two layers as input. Use one of them as the reference layer. The *Output layer* shows the *intersecting area* as **1**, while *non-intersecting area* is given **0**.

[image]

That's it.

You can then use this layer (commonly called **Mask**) to extract the intersecting area from two input layers by the Raster Calculator.

[image]

Multiplying the DEM (*E100N90@1*) with the mask (*Output layer@1*) (see above expression) will return the DEM for the "intersection".

[image]

(Likewise; *"Rectangle@1" * "Output layer@1"*).

Comment: Kazuhito and Babel, it was simply AWESOME!!! It worked pretty fine for me. Thanks a lot you both.