# Finding intersection between rasters using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-pro

I have three land classification rasters that overlap along their boundaries. The rasters are vegetation, sea and sand. I want to remove the overlaps using a weighted hierarchy where sand has the most weight and sea the lowest.

For example...

If the overlapping pixel is between sand and vegetation, convert the pixels to sand.

If the overlapping pixel is between sand and sea, convert the pixels to sand.

If the overlapping pixels is between vegetation and sea, convert the pixels to vegetation.

Here's an example diagram, showing overlapping pixels between three the sand, sea and vegetation rasters being converted by weight.

How can I do this in ArcGIS Pro?

Note - I would prefer to avoid converting to shapefile if possible and find a raster based solution, perhaps similar to this solution for [QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/386780/getting-intersection-between-two-rasters-using-qgis).

Details:

The attribute table for each raster simply contains 1 row with three fields (OBJECTID, Value and Count).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [Mosaic Rasters](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/raster-functions/mosaic-rasters.htm) function should give you the result you require.

You would specify the sand raster as the first raster in the mosaic list, then specify **First** for the operation parameter of the function.

If you don't want to create a single mosaicked raster and maintain the original three rasters, then you will possibly need the Spatial Analyst extension to perform a Conditional function on each input raster.

Comment: I've run the mosaic and it only partially works. The extent of the sand raster in the mosaic is as expected, however the pixels of the sea and vegetation rasters seem to be shifted to the right for some reason. To clarify, the sea and vegetation rasters maintain the correct raster shape but the pixels are all shifted a few to the right, meaning there is an offset between the original vegetation and sea rasters and the mosaic. Any idea what has happened?